# convert List to data table in R with Binary entries (0 or 1)

Tags: r, list

I have a list as below:

```
list("X1", c("X1", "X2"), "X3")
```

I want to transform this list to data table as follows:

1. The columns in data table will be as per all the unique entries in the list.
   In this example, the data frame will have columns - X1, X2, X3
2. The data table will have 3 rows as equivalent to length of list
3. Filling values in data table
   a) The data table will have binary values (0/1)
   b) For example, the row 1 will have column X1 as 1 while other columns (X2 and X3) as 0
   c) The row 2 will have columns X1 and X2 as 1 while X3 as 0 and so on.

The final output will look like as below:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 1, 0), X2 = c(0, 1, 0), X3 = c(0, 0, 
1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

As my list contains more than 80,000 elements, I am looking for a solution that uses *data table*.

Thanks,

Comment: I know you specifically asked for a `data.table` solution, but is the following not feasible? `names <- unique(unlist(l))` followed by `do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(x) sapply(names, function(y) +any(y == x), simplify = FALSE)))`

Comment: I don't think data.table can help much in this operation.

Comment: Yes, this is also very quick. Thank you..!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base way to get the same looking result.

```r
l = list("X1", c("X1", "X2"), "X3")
names(l) = seq_along(l)
t(table(stack(l)))
#>    values
#> ind X1 X2 X3
#>   1  1  0  0
#>   2  1  1  0
#>   3  0  0  1
```

To actually get this into a data.frame per your expected output, we can `apply` over our resulting table object to ultimately get it into a data.frame. Note, this is more work than expected.

```r
tbl = t(table(stack(l)))
res = as.data.frame(apply(tbl, 2L, list))
names(res) = colnames(tbl)

res
#>   X1 X2 X3
#> 1  1  0  0
#> 2  1  1  0
#> 3  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mtabulate` from "qdapTools":

```
> library(qdapTools)
> mtabulate(l)
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  0  0
2  1  1  0
3  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `purrr`:

```r
library(purrr)

x <- c("X1", "X2")

my_helper_function <- function(x) {
  out <- 
    matrix(rep(1, length(x)), nrow = 1) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
  colnames(out) <- x
  return(out)
}

list("X1", c("X1", "X2"), "X3") %>% 
  map_dfr(~my_helper_function(.x)) %>% 
  replace(., is.na(.), 0)
```